# When exactly am I considered a Novice Driver in France?

Tags: france, driving-licenses

In France, special rules apply to novice drivers for the first three years after they get their driver's license.

I am german, living in germany just a short distance from the border. I got a german issued EU car driver's license (class B) 12 years ago. Now I got an extension for motorcycles (class A).

When I make tours across the border and might get stopped by french police, from which date are the three years counted now, is it the date of the license being issued, or the date of the license becoming valid for a vehicle class? Does the rule maybe not apply to me at all because it only applies to licenses that were issued in France?

I expect that I do not need to follow the novice driver rules in a car, because I had the license for 12 years.
Do I need to follow the rules while I ride on a motorcycle?

Comment: The probationary period is only calculated from the first issuance of the driver's licence (or the re-issuance of the driver's licence after the licence is cancelled for cause). But yeah this question is not in scope since short-term travellers from other places are not concerned by these rules.

Comment: @xngtng in which case, if Thomas Blank is asking because he intends to drive in France as a short-term visitor, the question is on topic, even if the answer would be different were he a resident of France.  Thomas: what is your status in France and who issued your license?

Comment: @phoog Ah, I kind of assumed that the OP had a French licence. If it is for short-term driving though, the probationary period does not apply to holders of foreign licence; I'll wait for clarification from the OP.

Comment: @phoog There is the meta question that if the OP is a foreigner, how could the French authorities even know how long the OP has held the motorcycle endorsement?

Comment: Thomas FYI If people search for "Class A" and "Class B" licenses, a lot of the top hits will be for commercial truck driving license in the USA.  So as per phoog, knowing the source of the license can help.

Comment: @PeterM if it's a standard European license I believe the date will be shown on the back.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about traveling.

Comment: As far as I can see, the _only_ special rule for recently-qualified drivers relates to the legal blood alcohol limit. Is this the rule you're asking about, or are there more?

Comment: @mlc It would be about traveling if we knew the OP wasn't from Europe and wanted to use their freshly minted motorcycle license during a trip to France, and was concerned about breaking the rules.

Comment: Hi, I am german, my license is a german issued EU license and I live 20 km from the german-french border. I am asking this question for short motorcycle trips across the border. I am not an expatriate in France.

Comment: @AakashM There are also reduced Speed limits and the requirement to mark your vehicle.

Comment: @PeterM It's a german issued EU license. On the back it notes that it has been valud for class B since '08, for class A since '22. So, an eager gendarme could very easily make the case that I should be seen as a novice driver while on a motorcycle, with stricter rules and special requirements.

Comment: Driving, including how licenses work in other countries, do fit into this site, so I voted to re-open.

Comment: @phoog I clarified the question: I'd be a german short-time visitor with a german issued EU license. I't would be valid in France, I just don't know how their laws apply to me exactly. Dates on the back specify exactly when it became valid for cars and when it became valid for motorcycles, and they should look exactly the same in France, so a french police officer should be able to read all that just fine. Travel advisories from german automobile clubs do warn that novice drivers must adhere to the special rules on trips to France. None of them explain exactly when I'm a Novice Driver, though.

Comment: @xngtng As a short-term visitor, all other rules apply to me as well. Why would this single rule not apply to me? Does it only apply to drivers whose driver's license was issued in France?

Comment: This rule is unlikely to apply because of EU agreements on mutual license recognition. If Germany doesn't place a limit on your license, France can't place one either AFAIK. But I'll let someone better versed in EU law add an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for novice drivers (often somewhat misleadingly called *jeunes conducteurs* or "young drivers" whereas the age of the driver is irrelevant but rather the age of the driving licence matters) comes from the fact they have a *permis probatoire*, or probationary licence, which is in effect during the first three (or two, under conditions) years after a new driver's licence is issued to someone. Adding a category is not considered to create a new driver's licence, but simply a modification of the authorization contained in the licence. Obtaining a licence after the original licence is cancelled by authorities (due to e.g. loss of all points) however is considered as obtaining a new licence and a new probation period applies.

### For holders of foreign licences

In principle, all rules for licencing provided by French (or another country's) law are only for licences issued under French (or that country's) law, unless expressly provided as applicable to licences issued to another jurisdiction. For example, if French law requires 20 hours of practical instructions to obtain a driver's licence, your German licence obtained from 12 hours of practical lessons of course is not simply invalid because of that unless French law expressly conditions its acceptance on the hours of instructions (which would violate the EU directive, but that is just an example.)

For example, before 2016, foreign drivers cannot be concerned by demerits point under the French system. In 2016, a new provision had to be created in the Highway Code to expressly provide for a point system for foreign drivers, which is still completely separate from the system for French licences.

French law currently only apply probationary period to licences issued under the French law. The probationary period is introduced by the point system under [L223-1 of the Road Code](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000036749888).

This point system does not apply to holders of foreign licences as there exists a separate point system provided by [L223-10](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000033460330) (although the system has not been implemented).

Thus, drivers holding a foreign licence recognized as valid under French law (e.g. all EU licences) are not subject to the rules for probationary drivers (e.g. letter A sticker or special speed limits). However, if a holder of foreign driving licence wish to obtain a French licence, the licence obtained as such will be considered as a new licence and subject to probationary period (but the period count as starting from the grant of the foreign licence in case of exchange) ([the transportation department's response to a Senator's question](https://www.senat.fr/questions/base/2010/qSEQ101216300.html), see also [L223-11](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000033460328)).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The following is for a French license holder, most will not apply at all to you, I don't even think that foreign license holders are under the *permis probatoire* scheme as nothing is mentionned in that sense on official advice

> Avoir l'âge minimal pour conduire le véhicule de la catégorie équivalente de votre permis (au moins 18 ans pour le permis B) [...]

> Have the minimal age to drive a vehicle in the equivalent *(French)* category on your license (at least 18yo for B license)

from [service-public](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F34720/0_1?idFicheParent=N19126#0_1) (translations mine)

General info on the scheme :

If you have held any category of French license **continuously** (this resets if your license is invalidated) for more than 3 years (2 years or less in some cases that aren't important here), you have now a full license, and you will never be again under the regulation of the *permis probatoire*

> Vous avez un permis de conduire probatoire lorsque vous obtenez le permis pour la 1re fois ou à la suite d'une invalidation ou d'une annulation judiciaire.

Translation mine :

> You have a *permis probatoire* when you obtain the license for the first time or after an invalidation or judicial annulment

This is when you validate your first category, and doesn't apply to further categories that you may be adding

> Ainsi, si vous avez le permis B et passez le permis moto A2, le permis probatoire ne vous concerne pas.

> If you have a category B license and pass the exam for the A2 category (motorcycle license) the *permis probatoire* doesn't apply to you

From [service-public](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2390)

Comment: Thank you for those links, they are very helpful to understand how the point system works.